# Error when creating a directory from a table value

Tags: plsql

I want to create/modify an oracle directory using a procedure called by a trigger. I want to get the path from a value in a table, and the procedure is called from a trigger activated when that value has changed. I have the following code within the procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE update_directory(
    v_directory IN fe_system_parameter.value%type)
AS
  dir_path              VARCHAR2(32767);
  command VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT VALUE
  INTO dir_path
  FROM fe_system_parameter
  WHERE name = 'DWH_DIRECTORY';

  command := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DWH_DIR AS ' || dir_path;

  execute immediate(command);
END update_directory;
```

When dir has a value that contains '/' characters such as: /DIR/, I get the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
   stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading
   trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second
   timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr
   time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 140
ORA-06512: at "SOMESCHEMA.TRI_UPDATE_DIRECTORY", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SOMESCHEMA.TRI_UPDATE_DIRECTORY'
```

I don't know what the problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add single quotes, e.g.:

```
command := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DWH_DIR AS ''' || dir_path || '''';
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.